# Creating multi-line indent with hangparas

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, robust-commands

I'm trying to have all the text in a theorem or definition indented as it is usually done in books, however the hangparas environment just doesn't work for me and I have no idea why. Here is the entirety of my test file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hanging}

\theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{definitionn}{Definition}[section]
\def \STATEMENT#1{\vspace{8pt}\begin{hangparas}{16pt}{0}#1\par\end{hangparas}\vspace{8pt}}
\def \DEF#1{\STATEMENT{\begin{definitionn}#1\end{definitionn}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}

\DEF{
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Sed tempus tempor magna in dignissim. Nunc tempus pharetra
  mi id pulvinar. Nam vel purus ac eros varius pulvinar et in justo.
}

\end{document}
```

With this code, the result is

```
Definition 1.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed
tempus tempor magna in dignissim. Nunc tempus pharetra mi id pulvinar.
Nam vel purus ac eros varius pulvinar et in justo.
```

while what I want to achieve is either of those:

```
Definition 1.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed
                tempus tempor magna in dignissim. Nunc tempus pharetra mi id pulvinar.
                Nam vel purus ac eros varius pulvinar et in justo.
```

```
Definition 1.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed
    tempus tempor magna in dignissim. Nunc tempus pharetra mi id pulvinar.
    Nam vel purus ac eros varius pulvinar et in justo.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by `\leftskip` and `\hangindent`, here is an example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definitionn}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{definitionn}
  \hangindent=2em
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Sed tempus tempor magna in dignissim. Nunc tempus pharetra
  mi id pulvinar. Nam vel purus ac eros varius pulvinar et in justo.
\end{definitionn}

\begin{definitionn}
  \leftskip=2em
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Sed tempus tempor magna in dignissim. Nunc tempus pharetra
  mi id pulvinar. Nam vel purus ac eros varius pulvinar et in justo.
\end{definitionn}
\end{document}
```

[image]